# How can I resolve the 'Illegal characters in path' error when running Clang Tidy in VS 2019, and why is it unable to find the specified projects?

Tags: visual-studio-2019, clang-tidy

I get the below error when i run tidy:

```
--- CLANG TIDY STARTED ---

Get-ChildItem : Illegal characters in path.
At C:\users\praveer.kumar\appdata\local\microsoft\visualstudio\16.0_65aab50c\extensions\25p2uuw0.0vr\Tooling\v1\clang-b
uild.ps1:560 char:12
+    $slns = Get-ChildItem -recurse -LiteralPath $pathToCheck -Filter " ...
+            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-ChildItem], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
 
Cannot find given project(s)

--- CLANG TIDY FINISHED ---
```

[image]
Anyone has any idea how fix this error: